# Publishing Web tool that works with data on Portal for ArcGIS and using it in Web Appbuilder

Tags: arcgis-pro, geoprocessing-service, arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-portal, arcgis-python-api

I am trying to publish a web tool from ModelBuilder in ArcGIS Pro.
Inside my model there is (besides other things) a script. This script works with data on the same Portal that I want to publish the Webtool to. Consequently, I need to create a connection to the Portal inside the script.

```
gis = GIS(url="https://***/portal", username="***", password="***?", verify_cert=False)
```

The model works fine in ArcGIS Pro, the script does what I want, it applies some edits to data on Portal. However, when trying to publish the layer as a webtool, I always get an error message:

Error 00068: Script contains broken project data source

[image]

It seems that the problem is the connection to my Portal in the script. Is there any way to avoid that? I tried using a token instead of credentials, but the result is the same.

*EDIT*: Added error description

Comment: Error messages should always be included as text, since images are not legible on all devices or searchable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered [here](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-api-for-python-questions/error-00068-broken-data-source-when-trying-to/m-p/1029397/highlight/true#M5592) you should do some trick with portal url. GP publishing tool is confused when parses the script for files paths

> ```
> portalURL = "https:??gis.example.com?portal"
> portalURL = portalURL.replace('??', '//')
> portalURL = portalURL.replace('?', '/')
>
> gis = GIS(url = portalURL, username = 'geop', password = '****', verify_cert = False)
> ```

I made it like this:

```
from urllib.parse import urlunparse
portal_url = urlunparse(('https', 'geoportal.domain.com', 'portal', None, None, None)). #'https://geoportal.domain.com/portal'
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That worked for me